How to deploy a sail Laravel app in production
I've recently made a laravel app with sail, everything is good in the development environment.
Now I have been asked to deploy this app, I did some researches and most of them said you can't use docker in production (a friend of mine said something similar once too).
My question is how can I correctly deploy this app, espcially because it is dockerized?
I never did this so I hope you guys can point me to the right direction.

Sail is a development environment that utilizes docker, and you should not be using sail for a production environment. However it is not true that you cannot use docker at all. However typically what happens is you upload your source (that's your code files without the vendor, node_modules and the compiled javascript/css code and upload that to your production server where you run composer install, npm install && npm prod etc. There is also configuration involved, overall it's too broad a question to tackle here

I would just like to know how, like the actual steps.
I already have my project working with sail, I made a repository on github.
But I don't think my project will work when I clone it on the production server (because my project have sail which only work for dev mode).
So what should I do? can I deploy my application now? Should I just go with a normal laravel project instead??

I suggested cloning to the production server and running composer install and npm install && npm run prod. Make sure you have a .env file appropriate for production copied there are well. This should prepare the folder you cloned your project into for being served by a webserver as your production then you would need to configure your webserver which depends on which server you are using and there are instructions on how to do that in the relevant webserver documentations.

I did more research and discovered that it is important to create a new dockefile and docker-compose as well as an env file for prod use only.
I think the goal is to create a new docker image by picking the laravel application in the sail dev environment and then defining the docker image stack (apache, php, mysql...).
But I think I still need to install laravel  and docker on the prod server, is that right? and is there anything I am messing?
What do you think?

Yes you could do that. Just a couple of gotchas: Make sure you copy all files to both the php and apache container, also if you are using the public storage driver that will not work with this setup because the files get stored by the PHP container but are served by the apache container. Also if you use the laravel queue or the laravel scheduler you may need separate containers for those as well (also with all the files copied to them). For work I have one single container image that has PHP-FPM, supervisor, cron and nginx installed and run it 4 times with a different command each

Actually I am using the storage like you said, what's the solution for this? I want my files to be hosted in the prod server.
And can I share with you my Dockerfile and docker-compose files? so that u can give me tips please?

I'm not sure hosting your application on docker would be a good solution for you then. Just install the necessary software (apache, PHP-FPM, MySQL) directly on your production server and run it that way

Okay, I guess that's easier. Do you have or know a good guide to doing this properly?
Any tips would be great, thanks.

I have another question too, do you think I can use my current project that have sail in prod server and instead using sail, I waill just run it with php artisan.
Do you think that's gonna work? or should I create a new project?
